# Using absolute module paths in Typescript (requirejs paths config)

Tags: javascript, path, requirejs, typescript, amd

Is it possible to use module paths without having to use /// reference path.. with a .d.ts file?

For example if I have this in my requirejs config file :

```
require.config(
    {
       paths: {
          test : "/test/test1/TestFile"
       }
    }
);
```

I want to use :
import TestFile = require('test')

instead of having to use :
import TestFile = require('/test/test1/TestFile')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use : import TestFile = require('test') 
>   instead of having to use : import TestFile = require('/test/test1/TestFile')

Not at the moment. You need to have a complete relative path OR use a module declaration.

FYI : `grunt-ts` can generate these long relative paths for you https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/issues/85